# Scrolling 2 different elements in same time

Tags: javascript, dom

If i have a `textarea` element and a `div` element how can i scroll them both in one time? ( when i scroll `textarea` i want the `div` to do the same )

I want to use pure javascript, as simple code as it is possible.

Ty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As answered here: [synchronize two scrolling bars in multiple selection box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518041/synchronize-two-scrolling-bars-in-multiple-selection-box)

```
var s1 = document.getElementById('Select1');
var s2 = document.getElementById('Select2');

function select_scroll_1(e) { s2.scrollTop = s1.scrollTop; }
function select_scroll_2(e) { s1.scrollTop = s2.scrollTop; }

s1.addEventListener('scroll', select_scroll_1, false);
s2.addEventListener('scroll', select_scroll_2, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

While the question asked about doing it in pure JavaScript, if you want to do this with jQuery, all you need to do is tie the `scrollTop` property of one element to the `scrollTop` of the other, using a function tied to the scroll event.

Something along the lines of:

```
$('.linked').scroll(function(){
    $('.linked').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());    
})
```

With that function, all elements with a class of linked will scroll whenever you use the scrollbars of one of them. (I assumed vertical scrolling, if you wanted horizontal, do the same but with `scrollLeft`.)

See http://jsfiddle.net/g8Krz/ for a working example of the above.

Comment: Very nice, you can easily make 20 textareas scrll together.